# Adding new styles into external css sheet not html?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am a beginner and have a simple question - I am creating a site with HTML / CSS using Dreamweaver CS4. I have created an html page which includes divs for the elements I want on the page, and attached a style sheet to it. When I click on new CSS style rule for any of the elements, it modifies the HTML. I would like to modify the CSS instead, so that all the CSS rules automatically go into the attached style sheet.

I would really appreciate advice on how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.udel.edu/fth/webdesign/video/dreamweaver/css/dwCreateExternalCSS.html

(What you need is at 7:30)

When you add a CSS rule, it should ask you if you want to add it "in this document only" or in the css.